# Angular 2 route with dots

Tags: typescript, angular

When i navigate to url that contain a dot like: /track.t my application returns html with message:
Cannot GET /track.t

How to solve this issue? I need to redirect to ['Dashboard'];

Central component which handles routes:

```
export class AppComponent {
     constructor(router:Router, location:Location, translate:TranslateService) {
            console.log(location.path());
            router.recognize(location.path())
                .then((instruction) => {
                    if (!instruction) {
                        // this code will execute if there no route exists for the current url
                        router.navigate(['Dashboard']);
                    }
                });
    }
    }
```

Comment: I guess you need to create a bug report.

Comment: Angular2 Issue https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/8554

Comment: yes, i created that)